# Canvas scaler issue - displaying differently in browser and on phone

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this issue with my canvas scaler. I'm designing in Unity on my PC where it correctly displays how it's supposed to look. However, it looks very different in both the browser on my PC and on my android phone.

**PC - Unity:**

[image: PC - Unity]

**PC browser / Android phone (OnePlus 5):**

[image: PC - browser] [image: OnePlus 5 - android phone]

**Unity scene:** 

[image: scene]

**Canvas scaler settings:**

[image: Canvas scaler settings]

Everything is inside my canvas. I've tried tweaking the canvas scaler settings over and over again but with no luck. What could I be doing wrong? I'm using Unity 5.6.3p1.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas scaling looks to be working as expected.

However have you set your anchors correctly?

I would anchor your four buttons/images to each adjacent corner.

I would then anchor your center image to the center top and center bottom of the canvas.

Then when you switch screen size, the canvas scaler will keep things in relative place to the display screen.

See the unity docs on how to manage anchors.

UI Anchors:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html

UI Multi Resolutions:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html

Answer (score 0):

İt can be caused by simply if your camera does not fit on device screen exactly. To prevent this change *Render Mode* of your *Canvas* to the *Screen Space - Overlay*.